# Exponential Backoff Equations

Tags: summation

I'm admittedly not great at math, and I'm trying to work through the wikipedia article on exponential backoff, and there are a few things I don't fully understand.

The article says:

Given a uniform distribution of backoff times, the expected backoff time is the mean of the possibilities. That is, after c collisions, the number of backoff slots is in [0, 1, ..., N], where N = 2c − 1 and the expected backoff time (in slots) is
[this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho86X.png).

I understand how the summation symbol works, but I don't understand how it applies to the 1/N+1 expression. Do I calculate the final value of the summation and then multiply it by that fraction? Can someone give me a "plug and chug" example?

Then the article says: "and then calculate the mean of the backoff time possibilities" and provides [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOT78.png).

They lose me at that point. Are they saying these three expressions are equivalent or that one is the result of the next? How would I work through that equation?

Thanks!